# Thread safety without lock

Tags: c#, multithreading, image-processing

I have the following code in my imaging library which utilises a list of processors to dynamically manipulate images captured by a `HttpModule`.

At present there is only one instance of each processor created in order to keep memory overheads down and each of these processors have writeable properties which help determine the order in which to process each matched querystring parameter and store the parsed values to process.

As you can see I am currently wrapping the the methods functionality within a `lock` statement to prevent different threads from the `HttpModule` overwriting the processors properties though I know this could act as a bottleneck. What I am wondering is: Is there a design pattern or method by which I can make my processors threadsafe without the lock?

```cs
public static ImageFactory AutoProcess(this ImageFactory factory)
{
    if (factory.ShouldProcess)
    {
        // TODO: This is going to be a bottleneck for speed. Find a faster way.
        lock (SyncLock)
        {
            // Get a list of all graphics processors that 
            // have parsed and matched the querystring.
            List<IGraphicsProcessor> list =
              ImageProcessorConfig.Instance.GraphicsProcessors
              .Where(x => x.MatchRegexIndex(factory.QueryString) != int.MaxValue)
              .OrderBy(y => y.SortOrder)
              .ToList();

            // Loop through and process the image.
            foreach (IGraphicsProcessor graphicsProcessor in list)
            {
                factory.Image = graphicsProcessor.ProcessImage(factory);
            }
        }
    }

    return factory;

}
```

Comment: Do you have evidence that this *is* a bottleneck? Don't waste your valuable time coming up with dangerous and tricky solutions to problems you don't have. If it is a bottleneck then the first attempt at a solution should be to *move as much work as possible outside the lock* rather than trying to *eliminate the lock*. Uncontended locks are *extraordinarily fast*; we're talking nanoseconds. Contended locks are expensive; you can eliminate the contention by not doing so much work inside the lock.

Comment: To be honest, I don't. I would have just thought though that it would be. I've gone so far as optimising my ImageFactory class so that it doesn't need any locks around `Bitmap`s and it seemed wasteful to not have the process as optimised as possible considering I could be potentially processing thousands of images.

I didn't actually know they were that fast.

Answer (score 2):

A producer consumer queue may be of interest to you. Very generally, your `HttpModule` would receive events (the producer) and queue them to one or more instances of `IGraphicsProcessor` (the consumer(s)).

This is the canonical, simplest possible producer/consumer queue implementation: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Wait_Pulse_Producer_Consumer_Queue

If you are intent on eliminating locking, you should experiement with producer/consumer queues using a lock free queue implementation, such as `System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<T>` in .NET 4.0.

Comment: I'll have a look at this just now. I actually had page one open in another tab.

Answer (score 2):

Either you need to keep memory pressure down by not having multiple processors (and then you do need to allow at least a given processor to finish it's current work), or you need full concurrency.

Unless there is a clear reason not to, I would allow multiple instances of each image processor.  Ensure that the processor releases references to data it is acting on as early as possible to allow the GC to function optimally.  This has the virtues of simplicity, and good leverage of CPU cores.

If there is a clear reason to allow only one instance of each processor, you can improve your code by avoiding the current situation that you lock until *all* processors have finished their work.  Instead, you could have a mechanism to request each processor that you need work on the next item, once the current item is complete.  @anthony's suggestion to use a producer/consumer pattern seems like a solid solution to that.  Keep in mind that, with this approach, you will still bottleneck on the throughput of each individual filter and you may not be leveraging all CPU cores optimally.

Comment: One of the other main reasons behind only having one instance was extensibility. I'm loading up and creating on application start, all instances of an `IGraphicsProcessor` interface. The idea is that the library can be extended via drop in dll's.

Comment: If it is expensive to instantiate instances, you can use an object pool to manage N instances of pre-initialized objects. If it is not expensive to instantiate an instance, there's no reason to pre-create them.  Do you have concrete measurements (or expectations, for future plugins) that the initialization overhead will be high?

Comment: Well no. Any future implementation _should_ be lightweight. At present though, I would have to create and instance of all of them, every time I call the method in order to use the regex from each one to parse the querystring.

Comment: It seems that the knowledge of which parameters the processor can handle could be kept as a static property of the implementing class.  I don't see that instance data is needed to make that determination.  You could refactor to not require an instance to determine processor order.